# how to read task manager list using java program

Tags: java

I am trying to read the processes names from different REMOTE machines' task managers list.
i.e., A java program that keep polls into different remote machines task lists.

Can any one suggest a good solution for this...?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can use WMI for connection to remote windows machine and ssh to connect to uinx machine.

There are a lot of free SSH implementations for java. 
If you need WMI I'd recommed you jinterop.

for WMI use

select * from WIN32_Process;

for ssh use

ps command.

Window support telenet too, so you can connect to windows using telnet if you want.

Comment: Windows *support* telnet, but it's not enabled out-of-the-box (as opposed to WMI). With WMI/ssh+ps you should be able to cover most computers - note that you'll need to authenticate for WMI or SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way would be to have the remote machines publish their list of processes to authenticated clients - in other words, you'd need a "server" app on each of the remote machines, from which your client app would receive the process list.

Possible caveats:

- remote-side app needed to monitor processes on that machine (you can't just read the process list off any machine, you need their cooperation)
- authentication (you don't want *just anyone* to read the process list just by opening a connection to the remote server)
- encryption (you don't want people to snoop the list out of the network as it's transmitted)
- reliability (the server process may be slow/stop responding when computer is too loaded)
- observer effect (at the very least, you'll see your "process-list-server" as an additional process)